# How to acess property within a property in ant

Tags: ant

Hi all  please give a look to this code

in my properties file i have
win-x86.pc-shared-location=E:\Ant_Scripts

Now below i am trying to call `PrintInstallerName_build` from my build.xml,while as `PrintInstallerName_build` is in test.xml. In build.xml file,`${platform.id} has value=win-x86` in the calling target and in called target param1 also has value=win-x86

```
    <target name="PrintInstallerName" >
    <echo>PlatForm.Id====>${platform.id}</echo>
    <ant antfile="test.xml" target="PrintInstallerName_build">
        <property name="param1" value="${platform.id}"/>
    </ant>


<target name="PrintInstallerName_build" >
       <echo>${param1.pc-shared-location}</echo><!--${param1.pc-shared-location}-->
        <echo>${param1}.pc-shared-location}</echo><!--win-x86.pc-shared-location-->
    <echo>${win-x86.pc-shared-location}</echo><!--E:\\Ant_Scripts-->
</target>
```

as you can see only the last statement gives correct output but it is hardcoded,i want to use param1 and the output should be `E:\\Ant_Scripts` i tried to use $ and @ but none works,may be i am doing wrong somewhere can someone help please,i am struck and tomorrow is its DOD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variables from properties file in Ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747065/variables-from-properties-file-in-ant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<target name="PrintInstallerName_process" >
       <echo>${param1}</echo><!--win-x86-->

        <macrodef name="testing">
                <attribute name="v" default="NOT SET"/>
                <element name="some-tasks" optional="yes"/>
                    <sequential>
        <echo>Source Dir of ${param1}: ${@{v}}</echo><!-- Dir of Win-x86:E:\Ant_Scripts-->
                                                    <some-tasks/>
                    </sequential>
            </macrodef>

            <testing v="${param1}.pc-shared-location">
                <some-tasks>

                </some-tasks>
            </testing>
    </target>
```

this is the way it works and for me it works fine anyways `@sudocode` your tip took me there so thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

See *Nesting of Braces* in the [Properties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) page of the Ant Manual.

> In its default configuration Ant will not try to balance braces in
>   property expansions, it will only consume the text up to the first
>   closing brace when creating a property name. I.e. when expanding
>   something like ${a${b}} it will be translated into two parts:
>
> ```
> the expansion of property a${b - likely nothing useful.
> the literal text } resulting from the second closing brace
> ```
>
> This means you can't use easily expand properties whose names are
>   given by properties, but there are some workarounds for older versions
>   of Ant. With Ant 1.8.0 and the the props Antlib you can configure Ant
>   to use the NestedPropertyExpander defined there if you need such a
>   feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<propertycopy>` to make it happen.
Consider that you need to have the property value of `${propA${propB}}`

Use ant tag of `propertycopy` as follows:

```
<propertycopy property="myproperty" from="PropA.${PropB}"/>

<echo >${myproperty}</echo>
```

This will echo the value of `${propA${propB}}`

Comment: this is a golden line `<propertycopy property="myproperty" from="PropA.${PropB}"/>`