# Variables from properties file in Ant

Tags: android, ant

I have an Android app that needs to be built for different environments (e.g., UAT, staging, production, etc.). Each environment needs different properties (e.g., URLs, packages, etc.).

I would like to put all the different parameters into a single properties file and prefix each parameter with the environment it matches to.

For example, the properties file will contain `dev.home-url = http://home_dev.com` for the development environment and `prod.home-url = http://home.com` for the production environment.

I use the below to create a property that points to the properties file with a prefix of `params`:

```
<property file="parameters.properties" prefix="params" />
```

And to use a property, I use:

```
${params.home-url}
```

The problem comes when I need to add the prefix of the environment to the parameter.
It would end up looking like this, which obviously can't be done:

```
${params.${env-prefix}.home-url}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A frequently asked question about Ant is:

[How can I do something like `<property name="prop" value="${${anotherprop}}"/>` (double expanding the property)?](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#propertyvalue-as-name-for-property)

The following Ant build file was inspired by that FAQ.

**parameters.properties**

```
dev.home-url = http://home_dev.com
prod.home-url = http://home.com
```

**build.xml**

```
<project default="example">
    <property name="env-prefix" value="dev" />
    <property file="parameters.properties" prefix="params" />

    <macrodef name="propertycopy">
        <attribute name="name" />
        <attribute name="from" />
        <sequential>
            <property name="@{name}" value="${@{from}}" />
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="example">
        <propertycopy name="local.property" from="params.${env-prefix}.home-url" />
        <echo>${local.property}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

Executing the `example` task outputs:

```
Buildfile: /workspace/build.xml
example:
     [echo] http://home_dev.com
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 405 milliseconds
```

Comment: When reading from an external properties file the echo just prints out ${params.${env-prefix}.home-url} instead of the value for that property in the file.

Comment: I tried it also from an external properties file, and it worked. I updated my answer to reflect what I did. If the property didn't exist in the properties file, I would get `${params.dev.home-url}`. What version of Ant are you using (`<echo>${ant.version}</echo>`)? I am using 1.8.2.

Comment: Ah, I get the behavior you're seeing if `env-prefix` is not defined. If you're trying to execute the Ant build file from the command line, do `ant -Denv-prefix=dev`.

Comment: Also, if `env-prefix` is in your properties file, specify `from="params.${params.env-prefix}.home-url"`.

Comment: Yep looked like that did it. Thank you muchly