# passing multiple values dynamically in ant build.xml

Tags: ant

Am trying to do something like the below..

```
 <property name="INSTANCE_NAME" value="${PRODUCT5_JBOSS_INSTANCE}" />
```

`PRODUCT5_JBOSS_INSTANCE`-takes the value of that key name from a property file So when i give like the above my value for `INSTANCE_NAME = product5-jboss`.

But the above line is repeated multiple times for different products like

```
  <property name="INSTANCE_NAME" value="${PRODUCT6_JBOSS_INSTANCE}" />
   <property name="INSTANCE_NAME" value="${PRODUCT7_JBOSS_INSTANCE}" />
```

So inside `value="${PRODUCT7_JBOSS_INSTANCE}"` i would like to pass product7 dynamically like the below..

`value="${${PRODUCT_NUMBER}_JBOSS_INSTANCE}"` --But this doesnt work.Because two $ symbols doesnt work.My target now is `PRODUCT_NUMBER` should get the value as `PRODUCT7` and then 
 `PRODUCT7_JBOSS_INSTANCE` should get the value from file as `product7-jboss`

Can u help me with an approach for this

Comment: Duplicate of [Variables from properties file in Ant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10747065/127035)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this using a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html), as shown in the answer to the question [Variables from properties file in Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10747065/127035).

Here is an example of the same for your case.

```
<project default="test">

    <!-- override on command line -->
    <property name="PRODUCT_NAME" value="PRODUCT5"/>

    <property file="test.properties"/>

    <macrodef name="property-read">
        <attribute name="name"/>
        <attribute name="from"/>
        <sequential>
            <property name="@{name}" value="${@{from}_JBOSS_INSTANCE}"/>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="test">
        <echo>PRODUCT_NAME: ${PRODUCT_NAME}</echo>
        <property-read name="instance" from="${PRODUCT_NAME}"/>
        <echo>DYNAMIC PROPERTY VALUE: ${instance}</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Property definition:

```
$ cat test.properties
PRODUCT5_JBOSS_INSTANCE=product5.jboss.instance
PRODUCT7_JBOSS_INSTANCE=product7.jboss.instance
```

Output:

```
$ ant -DPRODUCT_NAME=PRODUCT7
Buildfile: C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build.xml

test:
     [echo] PRODUCT_NAME: PRODUCT7
     [echo] DYNAMIC PROPERTY VALUE: product7.jboss.instance

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
$
$
$ ant -DPRODUCT_NAME=PRODUCT5
Buildfile: C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build.xml

test:
     [echo] PRODUCT_NAME: PRODUCT5
     [echo] DYNAMIC PROPERTY VALUE: product5.jboss.instance

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach provided.The above works perfectly if you specify the below line in build.xml                          <property name="PRODUCT5_JBOSS_INSTANCE" value="product5.jboss.instance"/>
    <property name="PRODUCT7_JBOSS_INSTANCE" value="product7.jboss.instance"/>   When am trying to read the same from property file it doesnt work and gives value as {PRODUCT5_JBOSS_INSTANCE}

Comment: It works for me. I updated the example to load properties. I think the result you get indicates that either you don't load the required property file, or that the property key is different from expected.

Comment: Yes i have used the wrong property file..Now it works amazing.Thanks a lot