# How do i know at runtime in Android if it is a test or a live environment?

Tags: testing, runtime, live, environment

How do i know at runtime in Android if it is a test environment runned from Eclipse or a signned version installed from the Market? (i need to run some debug code only when testing, because in live i get some ANR reports caught when running this code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html

```
boolean isDebuggable =  ( 0 != ( getApplcationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE ) );
```

will let you know it if is debuggable, you can then save this to a shared pref or some other method and then check it whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to. You can just log them in Log.d level and then use a tool such as ProGuard to remove such logs

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

More explanation in this answer [Remove all debug logging calls before publishing: are there tools to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/remove-all-debug-logging-calls-before-publishing-are-there-tools-to-do-this/2466662#2466662)

EDIT

If that is the case you need to have some sort of boolean value in an external properties file and conditonally write logs.

More info on that here
[Variables from properties file in Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747065/variables-from-properties-file-in-ant)

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is not what i have asked, i do not only need to remove Log messages, but some other code too, so the only thing a need is a simple true/false condition before running the debug code. Is this possible?