# Use Property value as a Key to read another value from Properties file

Tags: ant

For Ant Script I have following `myBuild.properties` file

```
p.buildpath=c:\production\build

d.buildpath=c:\development\build
```

I wrote following `build.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Test Project" default="info">
    <property file="myBuild.properties"/>
      <target name="info">
        <input
            message="Please enter the Server Name(p: production, d: development)?"
            validargs="p,d"
            addproperty="do.Server"
        />
    <echo>Your Server type: ${do.Server} </echo>

    <property name="myserv.buildpath" value="${do.Server}.buildpath" />
    <property name="newProperty" value="${myserv.buildpath}" />

    <echo>New Property Value: ${newProperty}</echo>
    <!-- Following is an incorrect syntax -->
    <echo>Build Path: ${${newProperty}}</echo>

  </target>
</project>
```

When I run it using:

> c:\>ant

I get following Output:

> Buildfile: C:\build.xml
>
> info:
>       [input] Please enter the Server Name(p: production, d: development)? (p, d)
>   p
>            [echo] Your Server type : p
>            [echo] New Property Value: p.buildpath
>            [echo] Build Path: ${${newProperty}}
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>   Total time: 2 seconds

I want to echo the "Build Path" value same as `p.buildpath` value.
How is it possible to do in above case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to acess property within a property in ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703148/how-to-acess-property-within-a-property-in-ant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the macrodef advice of [Ant Faq](http://ant.apache.org/faq#propertyvalue-as-name-for-property) you need no Ant addons like antcontrib, it's foolproof :

```
<project>

  <macrodef name="cp_property">
   <attribute name="name"/>
   <attribute name="from"/>
   <sequential>
    <property name="@{name}" value="${@{from}}"/>
   </sequential>
  </macrodef>

  <property file="myBuild.properties"/>

   <input
    message="Please enter the Server Name(p: production, d: development)?"
    validargs="p,d"
    addproperty="do.Server"
   />
    <echo>Your Server type: ${do.Server}</echo>

   <cp_property name="myserv.buildpath" from="${do.Server}.buildpath"/>  

   <echo>$${myserv.buildpath} : ${myserv.buildpath}</echo>

</project>
```

output :

```
[input] Please enter the Server Name(p: production, d: development)? (p, d)
p
[echo] Your Server type: p
[echo] ${myserv.buildpath} : c:/production/build
```

btw. Within your propertyfile **you need to change your path separator** to either `unix style '/'` (when on windows ant will handle it correctly) or `double '\\'` , otherwise with :

```
p.buildpath=c:\production\build
d.buildpath=c:\development\build
```

you'll get something like :

```
[input] Please enter the Server Name(p: production, d: development)? (p, d)
p
[echo] Your Server type: p
[echo] ${myserv.buildpath} : c:productionbuild
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681686/130683 for a very similar problem solved with [Props antlib](http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/props/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it **without additional tools** this way (edited/revised version):

```
<project name="Test Project" default="info">
    <property file="myBuild.properties"/>
        <target name="info">
            <input
                message="Please enter the Server Name(p: production, d: development)?"
                validargs="p,d"
                addproperty="do.Server"
            />
        <echo>Your Server type: ${do.Server} </echo>

        <property name="buildstage.production" value="p.buildpath" />
        <property name="myserv.buildpath" value="${do.Server}.buildpath" />

        <echo>New Property Value: ${myserv.buildpath}</echo>

        <condition property="isProduction">
            <equals arg1="${buildstage.production}" arg2="${myserv.buildpath}" />
        </condition>

        <antcall target="production" />
        <antcall target="development" />
    </target>

    <target name="production" if="${isProduction}">
        <echo>Build Path: ${p.buildpath}</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="development" unless="${isProduction}">
        <echo>Build Path: ${d.buildpath}</echo>
    </target>
 </project>
```

**Core idea** is using a `<conditional>` task for a test on the selected property key and calling two tasks named `production` and `development`, where the first runs if the property `isProduction` is avaluated to true, the second if not (`unlesss`).

The condition is checked against a property named `buildstage.production` which is set to the property key `p.buildpath` as discriminator.

With "property key" I reference to the keys in the properties file. A hole bunch of "properties" here, could be confusing :)

By the way: you need to escape the **backslashs** in the property values as follows, otherwise they won't be echoed:

```
p.buildpath=c:\\production\\build
d.buildpath=c:\\development\\build
```

Comment: BUILD FAILED: condition doesn't support the nested "property" element.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edited the code and tested it fully. Now it should run.

Comment: This solution works(+1), but I need to manage to much conditions. Also, if I add "Testing" environment to it, my code maintenance increases.

Answer (score 0):

How it says in this post (http://ant.apache.org/faq#propertyvalue-as-name-for-property), without any external help, it's tricky.

With AntContrib (external task library) you can do `<propertycopy name="prop" from="${anotherprop}"/>`.

Anyway, there are other alternatives in the same post. 
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way that does not require `macrodef` or antcontrib:

```
<property name="a" value="Hello"/>

<property name="newProperty" value="a"/>
<loadresource property="b">
    <propertyresource name="${newProperty}"/>
</loadresource>

<echo message="a='${a}'"/>
<echo message="b='${b}'"/>
```